# iOS: How to cast a shadow across multiple UIViews / UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uikit

NOTE: I am not interested on how to draw a Shadow on a UIView. This is already done and the code is also shown below.

I have a `UITableView` that contains a series of sections.

Each `Section` has its own `UIView` as a `HeaderView`.

Each `Section` has one cell, that has embedded inside a `UIViewController` (the `UIView` of the controller, but this is implementation details, as the same issue arises with normal cells with no content)

The cell have a internal View that cast a shadow, with a big blur parameter: 24

The structure looks something like that

```
UITableView
-> HeaderView
-> TableViewCell
--> View With Shadow with Blur 24
-> HeaderView
-> TableViewCell
--> View With Shadow with Blur 24
-> HeaderView
-> TableViewCell
--> View With Shadow with Blur 24
```

**Problem:**

The shadow is drawn in the view/cell but does not draw over the other headers/cells.

I would say this is normal behaviour.

I would like to cast the shadow outside the bounds of the cell.

`clipToBound` and `maskToBound` are already set to false (as default on each UIView)

**What it currently Looks Like**:

You can see the shadow is clipped at the end of the cell and is not drawn on the section header before or after the cell

[image: problemImage]

**What I am trying to achieve**:

I would like the shadow to drop over the bounds of the cell and spread on the remaining UIviews, even if the common ancestor is only the `UITableView`

[image: toachieve]

**Notes**:

I can't reduce the blur radius to fit the Cell frame. I need to have it that big.

The code for the shadow is the usual:

```
shadowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
shadowView.layer.shadowColor = profileShadowColor.cgColor
shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 6)
shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 20
```

Comment: Is it only being clipped by the section header? I wonder if you could make the section header with a clear background to allow the shadow to go behind it.

Comment: @JoshHrach as an experiment I did remove all backgrounds apart the `tableView` one. So everything is clear. Still the shadow is cropped. I suspected it could have been due to the order of the Views in the tableView, but it looks like the cells and sections are on the same level from the inspector. They are just different entities and UIKit doesn't seem to be able to "overcast" the shadow